# NSString: Why use static over literal?

Tags: objective-c, static, nsstring, string-literals

The Master-Detail Xcode Project Template generates code like:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

1. Why declare the `NSString` as `static`? Why not just use the string literal, like below?

   ```
   // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {        
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
       if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
       }

       [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
       return cell;
   }
   ```
2. When should I use static over literals with `NSString`, `NSObject`, scalors (`NSInteger`, `CGFloat`, etc.), etc.?
3. Is it more performant to use a literal `NSInteger` rather than defining a static variable that points to it and using that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The static allows you to define only one instance of the NSString object to be used. If you used the string literal instead, there's no guarantee that only one object will be created; the compiler may instead end up allocating a new string every time the loop is called, and then passing that to the dequeue method, which will use string comparison to check if any cell is available.

In practice, there's no difference; both static or literal will work fine. But with the static you're telling Obj-C that it should use the same instance every time. Although for this case this would very unlikely cause any problems for you, it's good practice to use static if you plan to always use the same object.

Comment: I agree. Just adding a little more. Using the static variable instead of only literal makes your code easier to maintain since you only change the string in one place. / And about the NSInteger and CGFloat they aren't objects so it's a little different.

Comment: Both an excellent answer and an well-put comment - both memory management and code maintainability at stake here.

Comment: From the perspective of code legibility, what you say is true, however it should be noted that literal strings in ObjC are created at compile time and stored in the DATA segment of the binary. A literal string is both immortal and reused.

Comment: @FelipeCypriano can you elaborate on when I should use `static` for `NSInteger` & `CGFloat`? I notice Three20 does this a lot at the top of `.m` files for scalar constants that are used a few places in the file.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I was just pointing out that it's common to think that NSIntegers and CGFloats are objects but they are C primitives. / I just googled and find out that basically a static variable in C is kept in memory throughout all the program execution: http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html

Comment: @FelipeCypriano yes, but aren't literal C primitives also kept in memory throughout the entire program run? Is there an extra performance hit for assigning a primitive literal to a static variable?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I don't know. Is this a good question to post on Programmers?